# Import file from url instead of upload

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've used [file upload example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) to add files to an entity. Now I'm trying to import the existent files from the previous project (in WordPress). I've wrote a script that imports the current database in Symfony2.

All is going well, except for the file uploads. I want to rename the files ([using the id as the filename](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-the-id-as-the-filename)). The example uses a request to handle the form, but since I'm using a current database to get the data, there isn't a request.

I've tried this:

```
$old_image = '../../../public_html/uploads/images/'.$filename;

$file = new UploadedFile($old_image, '337-1.jpg');

$img = new Entity\Image();
$img->setFile($file);

$this->em->persist($img);
```

I'm getting this error:

`The file "337-1.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error.`

How can I set a file without using a form (and request)?

Comment: Where do you have the logic that actually copy the uploaded file to the final directory structure?

Comment: @AlbertoFernández There isn't a 'uploaded' file. It's already in the filesystem. I'm using this example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html#using-the-id-as-the-filename

Comment: Then why are you using the `UploadedFile` if you already have an uploaded file? Could you post the rest of the `Entity` structure?

Comment: I've used the example and didn't make any change to it. I would like to add a file to my entity by copying (and renaming) it.

Comment: Maybe the [HttpFoundation/File](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html) more appropriate for your usecase

Comment: @ferdynator That's what I thought too, but it gives a fatal error: ``Argument 1 passed to ***\AppBundle\Entity\Image::setFile() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile, instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File given``

Comment: Remove that constraint from your `Image::setFile()` method. And you should be good to go.

Comment: @ferdynator Thanks, that's it! If you post it as your answer, I can give you the credits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the [HttpFoundation/File](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.html) entity should be more appropriate for your usecase. Also make sure to change the signature of your `Image::setFile()` method from:

```
public function setFile(File $file)
```

to:

```
public function setFile($file)
```